# tinymce blank content on ajax form submit?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, forms, tinymce

My form uses TinyMCE to format HTML, but somehow the content is always blank on first submission. This is what I have for the submit function:

```
$('#commentForm').click('submit', function () {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#commentForm')[0].reset();
                    var newComment = { comment: result.comment };
                    // Append the new comment to the div
                    $('#commentTemplate').tmpl(result.comment).appendTo('#commentsTemplate');
                }
                $('#commentFormStatus').text(result.message);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

I've added `tinyMCE.triggerSave(true,true);` but it doesn't seems to work. Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you submitting here?

Comment: Just text, might have HTML in it. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try to replace

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);
```

by

```
tinyMCE.get("id").save();
```

where "id" is the ID of your textarea.

Comment: I too had some variation of `triggerSave()` glad you posted this.

Answer (score 3):

Important: If you call tinymce() twice or more times on the same textarea, any save() methods will be not working probably. (I have function called at each DOM change)

So, I fixed this by removing class:

```
$('textarea.tinymce').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('tinymce');
    .......
```

Comment: My issue was indeed the tinymce being called multiple times

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how it´s works.

I was taking problems with firefox, and I solved using this workarroud

**on submit button: and my text field is called "Contenido"**

```
tinyMCE.get("Contenido").setContent(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());
document.getElementById("Contenido").value=tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have few TINYMCE in form: before submit call

```
jQuery(tinymce.get()).each(function(i, el){
        document.getElementById(el.editorId).value = el.getContent();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').on('submit', function(form){
    // save TinyMCE instances before serialize
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:       'POST',
        cache:      false,
        url:        'inc/process.php',
        data:       data,
        success:    function(){
                        console.log("Updates have successfully been ajaxed");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As of version 4.2.5 (and probably earlier) you do not appear to need to do anything. It just saves the values as you edit (probably on blur).

Once thing I did notice, is that accidentally applying TinyMCE more than once to the same element stops the normal save behavior. This had me failing with *all* the other solutions, until I noticed that the solution by `@Ксана Лысак` was running the `each` twice on the same element.

After ensuing that TinyMCE could only be applied to each `textarea` once, it worked just fine without help.

Answer (score 0):

Good solution. Ксана Лысак

But for me it needed slight modification, may be due to version 4.1, I had to use **el.id** instead of **el.editorId**

```
$("#thesubmit").click(function(e){
    $(tinymce.get()).each(function(i, el){
        if(el.id)
            document.getElementById(el.id).value = el.getContent();

});
```